# How do you find only text files using filepath.Walk()?

Tags: file, go

I'm using `filepath.Walk()` to search through all the files in a directory. I'm implementing a search tool, so I'm only interested in opening files with text in them. I'm wondering if there's a way to ignore stuff like binary files that I wouldn't want to search through. I'm trying to minimize os calls, so it would be great if this could be done with just `os.FileInfo`.

Comment: I don't think `os.FileInfo` is sufficient or by checking the file extension. Unless you scan the file content to see whether the file contain non text character (ASCII or UNICODE)

Comment: I don't think the question is how to identify text files by the file name, but rather how to identify text files by looking at the content. If that's the case, the only thing you can do is inspect the contents of the file. If by "text file" you mean UTF-8, you can use functions in the `utf8` package to determine if the file contains valid UTF-8.

Comment: Write a function that checks each file, according to whatever definition of "text file" you find appropriate. If you have problems with that, show us your code, and explain your specific problem.

Comment: Yes, what is this thing you call a "text file?" It seems like something humans know about their own files but don't bother telling their machines.

Comment: I realize this is now highly subjective. I think the fastest way (although not infallible) would be to check a portion of the file for valid utf8 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know if a file (or any byte stream) contains only "text" is to read the entire contents of the stream and determine if every rune is a "text" character according to your definition.

For example, one might consider a file "ASCII text" if all runes have integer values in `[0,128]`, are not control characters, or are whitespace:

```
func isASCIITextStream(rd io.Reader) (bool, error) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(rd)
    for {
        r, _, err := reader.ReadRune()
        if err == io.EOF {
            return true, nil // Every rune was text.
        }
        if err != nil {
            return false, err // Unexpected error.
        }
        if !isASCIIText(r) {
            return false, nil // At least one rune was not text.
        }
    }
    return true, fmt.Errorf("did not find EOF") // Unexpected state.
}

func isASCIIText(r rune) bool {
    x := int64(r)
    return (x >= 0) && (x <= 128) && (!unicode.IsControl(r) || unicode.IsSpace(r))
}
```

Of course, most people would consider many other Unicode character classes as containing "text", so whatever your approach is, the [`unicode`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/) package will likely be helpful for classifying runes.